# How to Hide Overlapping Text of Labels in D3 Zoomable Pack Layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, overlap, circle-pack

I am using the Zoomable Pack Layout provided on the D3 website: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/pack-hierarchy.html

[image]

All labels of the circles are displayed when the layout is displayed.

The problem is that for small circles which are close together, the labels overlap. I would like to know if there is a way to hide the overlapping text of the labels?

I have read about "foreignobject", but if this is the answer, I am not sure how and where to incorporate it in the code.

Comment: D3 doesn't provide any functionality for this. You would need to check yourself if labels overlap and which ones to hide.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, I also received assistance for this question that I made use of, which can be found on the following link: http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/2013/10/28/circle-pack-label-truncation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could restrict the display of text based on either the level of the hierarchy, the radius of the circle or a combination of both. Both are in the pack output. Use titles for hover detail.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply - I have implemented the hover detail as you have suggested and also posted a link to a solution I received regarding the overlapping text, which uses the radius of the circle, again, like you suggested.