# stop d3 circle pack labels from overlapping

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, zooming, circle-pack

Stuck on overlapping labels. To illustrate: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/airwwwave/h5s6cv7u/)

1. Click on the text label "Group A". After the zoom transition, the
   Group A label remains causing overlap with the small circle's label.
2. Click elsewhere to zoom out.
3. Click on "Group A" again. This time the label does not remain, so
   there is no overlapping. So it seems to fix itself after one time.

I want no overlapping the first time something is clicked. How do I do this? I don't want to truncate labels or reposition labels.

I've been fiddling with this bit, but no luck so far.

```
transition.selectAll("text")
        .filter(function(d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
        .each("start", function(d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
        .each("end", function(d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
```

FYI, this also occurs if the first click is on a medium circle.

[This post gets close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607281/how-to-hide-overlapping-text-of-labels-in-d3-zoomable-pack-layout), by saying its possible to restricting visibility using the pack output, but doesn't say how to achieve it.

So basically I'm trying to do something like this: "If zoomed to the level of medium or small circle, don't show medium circle label."

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having the same problem. I have figured out that a particular piece of the zoom function, if applied on the root immediately after generating the intial view, fixes this issue. Adding this code to the end of your d3.json file should do the trick. Still investigating for a better solution.

```
init(root)
function init(d) {
  var transition = d3.transition()
  transition.selectAll("text")
    .each("start", function(d) {
      if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline";
    });
}
```

Comment: Boom! That did it, thank you. That makes sense that you'd have to get the fix in there immediately after the initial view, and you figured it out. Thanks so much! [JSFIDDLE ANSWER](http://jsfiddle.net/airwwwave/9vzx2s3v/) (though this doesn't work in the jsfiddle results pane, you have to run it.